# Stop other calendars from modifying my own

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

How do I stop other calendars from modifying my own calendar?

It would seem that items added in other calendars, All Group Calendars/TeamNameHere, are being added in mine.

I was working with an empty calendar this afternoon and suddenly got interrupted multiple times with an unexpected popup and would like to stop these from occurring.

Suddenly being surprised with a meeting or event you didn't remember accepting and this is not relevant and should be ignored, is annoying and distracting.

**Edit #1**

The red line indicates the offending calendar. Everything else is **unchecked**.

[image]

**Edit #2**

Essentially, clear calendar, sudden meeting reminder, calendar now shows taken up slot, no inbox meeting invite, change coming from another calendar.

Comment: Can You confirm you get notifications despite there is no event in the calendar

Comment: Essentially, I had nothing there, suddenly get a notification, look into my calendar and something was added but I didn't get any invite. I navigate to the offending calendar and it was added there and mirrored (?) in mine?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you have several calendars(your own calendar and other calendars) in your Outlook, and the events in the calendars are added into your own calendar?

If so, please close the other calendars and check if there're any differences.

Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

If the above is invalid, please provide more information about your case for our better research:

- What's the type of your account(Exchange/POP/IMAP)? If it's an
  Exchange account, have you given a permission to your delegate to
  modify your calendar?
- What's the "unexpected popup" you mentioned? Could you please provide
  a screenshot?  (In order to avoid the disclosure of your privacy,
  please remember to hide your personal information)
- And have you done any specific operations before the issue occurred?

Comment: See Edit 1.

These are all Exchange related. The popup is the default Outlook meeting reminder.

Essentially, I have an empty afternoon and get surprised with meeting reminders that are coming from that problematic Calendar and getting mirrored in my own.

The only change is our team started to use the offending Calendar to indicate leave.

Comment: Have you tried to close other calendars or start Outlook in Safe mode? If they are invalid, it's suggested that you could create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

Comment: All the calendars are unchecked, which leads me to believe that they are closed.

Comment: Maybe you can create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: It's a corporate system, that I don't have much rights over, thus I can't really mess with accounts, etc. I was trying to see if I could find a way, through a built in Outlook menu, that I could use to keep my calendar clean. It doesn't seem like it's possible.

Comment: Re creating the profile won't mess up your account. Of course, if you don't have permission, there's nothing to say. As far as the current outlook client is concerned, do you set some moving rules or others when processing your calendar? In addition, have you done some operations in the web mail?

Comment: No rules are in place nor have I used web mail.

Comment: Do other user in your group encounter the same issue? If so, the issue may be related to the action "The only change is our team started to use the offending Calendar to indicate leave".

Comment: Yes, impacting everybody. It seems to be annoying me considerably more than the others :)

Comment: If so, how did your team started to use the offending Calendar to indicate leave? It's suggested that you could contact your team to stop the event.